# how does self-join work? (ms sql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, self-join

how/why would the result set of this: (returns 1215 records)

```
SELECT UM2.UCN_Group, UM2.UCN, UM2.Cust_EDP 
FROM CleanRoom.dbo.UCN_Master AS UM 
     JOIN CleanRoom.dbo.UCN_Master AS UM2
          ON UM.UCN_Group = UM2.UCN_Group
WHERE UM.UCN_Group NOT LIKE 'EXPN%'
```

be different from this: (returns 1203 records)

```
SELECT UM2.UCN_Group, UM2.UCN, UM2.Cust_EDP 
FROM CleanRoom.dbo.UCN_Master AS UM2 
WHERE UM2.UCN_Group NOT LIKE 'EXPN%'
```

shouldn't the JOIN condition on the first query ensure same result set from both queries? TIA

Comment: What happens if you change the first query to `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Adding DISTINCT to the first query resulted in having the same number of records (1203). Why did that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the only reason for this: you've got rows with identical `UCN_Group` values.

Comment: granting. why wouldn't the number of rows be equal?

Comment: because you're creating a cartesian product between rows with the same value.

Comment: @Barmar is correct. In short join does 2 things: a) pair each row from table 1 to each row from table 2 b)output only those pairs which meet the ON criteria. Read this article to understand how joins work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Perhaps you can enhance your answer with a simple demo, using a table with 3-4 rows.

Comment: @Isantipov since its a self-join, my understanding from a & b is i would get the same number of records. my apologies but my newbie mind cannot comprehend why records were duplicated. anyway thanks for taking the time to answer. i really appreciate it guys!

Comment: also, any guesses why anyone would do query 1; is there any practical reason?